# Angular2 tutorial Tour of Heroes: User interaction is shared between all connected users

Tags: angular

a Angular1/2 newbie here.

I did the Angular2 tutorial (Tour of Heroes), and got it working just fine. But I happened to try it from two computers at the same time (one of them acting as the server), and I noticed that when I selected a hero on one computer, the same hero got selected on the other computer as well. Both computers were viewing the Heroes page, which displays the list of available heroes. This same happens when viewing the same page on one computer but with two browsers (note: for some reason this does NOT happen if I have two tabs in one Chrome instance).

Can someone explain to me what's happening, and how would I make it so that the interaction is not shared between users?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out (using Wireshark) that the reason for this was browser-sync from lite-server.